# Where can I find the SECRET_KEY of existing Mezzanine Project?

Tags: django, mezzanine, pythonanywhere

I am trying to upload my existing mezzanine project in pythonanywhere.com. However, I always get an error that the SECRET_KEY should not be empty. When I looked into the settings.py, the SECRET_KEY is not there.

In the mezzanine documentation, it says that the SECRET_KEY is automatically created after the command "mezzanine-project". But, where is it? How do I know the SECRET_KEY?

Thank you!

Comment: check your `local_settings.py`. hth :)

Comment: it's not there. That's why I'm wondering why I can't find it in a mezzanine project, but in a regular Django project, SECRET_KEY is there.

Comment: Have you tried using grep to see if it's anywhere in the source tree?  For example, `grep -Ir SECRET_KEY ~/mysite/`

Comment: @GilesThomas it is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Mezzanine 4.0.0, the `SECRET_KEY` is populated automatically in [local_settings.py](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/project_template/project_name/local_settings.py.template) in new projects.

In existing projects (or to rotate keys), one way to generate a new one is to simply make a new project and copy the `SECRET_KEY`:

```
$ mezzanine-project tmp
$ cat tmp/tmp/local_settings.py | grep "SECRET_KEY.*="
SECRET_KEY = "dontusesthisstringfromstackoverflowasyoursecretkey"
$ rm -rf tmp
```